# Powershell $Host.UI.ReadKey() Menu loop - Key not resetting

Tags: loops, powershell, menu, key

I have created several menu scripts for executing several jobs. But they all have the same problem:

**When you press a key, it's job is executed not once, but twice or even thrice**

My code is as follows:

```
Function Write-Menu{
Write-Host ""
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline "Enter"; Write-Host " Job description"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host ""
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline "  A  "; Write-Host " Job 2 description"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline "  B  "; Write-Host " Job 3 description"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host -BackgroundColor Black -NoNewline "  C  "; Write-Host " etc.."
}
Write-Menu
Do {
$key = $null
$key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()
Sleep -Milliseconds 250
If ($key.Character -eq 13) {
    #Do Something..
}
If ($key.Character -eq etc) {
    #etc..
}
Clear-Host
Write-Menu
} Until(!($CloseMenu = "false"))
```

I have tried everything to stop it but nothing fixed this issue. I don't see anyone else having this issue either..

It seems to save your pressed key code for 2 or 3 loops regardless of any delay / sleep time, the variable being cleared / reset and regardless of what code is within it. Even if I start a java process that closed 8 hours later is still does that. I have no idea why this is even happening.

Only closing the menu seems to work well ^^

I have thought of setting up the loop differently but I can't think of any setup. Can I have some assistance? Thanks

Comment: where is $CloseMenu set to true ?  `$CloseMenu = "false"` are you sure you dont want `$CloseMenu -eq $false ` ?

Comment: yes, the loop never ends unless the script is closed, which is also a "job"

Comment: Did you try `$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown") ` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()` reads key pressed, key released, a combination of the two, and can display them on the console, hence your "2-3 keys" read.

To control better how it behaves you can use the options parameter which is a bitmask of one or more of the following:

```
  IncludeKeyDown 
  IncludeKeyUp
  NoEcho
```

By passing "NoEcho, IncludeKeyDown" to ReadKey you basically are telling it to ignore key up events, and not echo anything.

More about it here : [Source from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)